# golang gorm upsert with returning

Tags: go, go-gorm

In my golang project I use gorm and I need to make upsert query with returning clause to get the modified value from the query. I can make upsert, but I cannot figure out how to connect the returnning clause to it. The table name is counters, the code is as follows:

```
te := struct {
        Name string //key column
        Counter int
    }{
        Name: "name_to_update",
        Counter: 2,
    }

DB.
    //Model(te).
    Clauses(
        //clause.Returning{Columns: []clause.Column{{Name: "counter"}}},
        clause.OnConflict{
            Columns: []clause.Column{{Name: "name"}}, // key column
            DoUpdates: clause.Assignments(map[string]interface{}{
                "counter": gorm.Expr("counters.counter + ?", 1),
            }),
        },
    ).Create(&te)
```

The resulting SQL query is:

```
INSERT INTO "counters" ("counter", "name") VALUES (0, "name_to_update") ON CONFLICT ("name") 
DO UPDATE SET "counter"=counters.counter + 1 RETURNING "name" //I need updated counter value here, not name
```

So the counter is updated and this is OK, but it returns me the key column (in RETURNING) while I need the updated value of the counter. Any ideas how to fix it? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if the anonymous struct causes an issue.

Also, it's unclear from your code where the table name - **"counters"** - comes from.

I've tried your solution - but with a dedicated struct for the model - and it works just fine.

```
type Counter struct {
    Name    string `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Counter int
}

...

counter := Counter{Name: "name_to_update", Counter: 2}

    db.
        Clauses(
            clause.Returning{Columns: []clause.Column{{Name: "counter"}}},
            clause.OnConflict{
                Columns: []clause.Column{{Name: "name"}},
                DoUpdates: clause.Assignments(map[string]interface{}{
                    "counter": gorm.Expr("counters.counter + ?", 1),
                }),
            },
        ).Create(&counter)

    fmt.Println(counter.Counter)
```

The code above generates the following SQL

```
INSERT INTO "counters" ("name","counter") VALUES ('name_to_update',10) ON CONFLICT ("name") DO UPDATE SET "counter"=counters.counter + 1 RETURNING "counter"
```

And `counter.Counter` has correct updated value.

Comment: Finally I got it, it was gorm version issue, I had 1.21, updated to current (1.24.2) and it worked, thank you